# How to tackle Class level changes in REST API

Tags: asp.net, json, api, schema, rest

I have REST Service Provider which we use for CRUD operations.

My Front end accesses third Party API through our ASP.net Web API

Third Party REST Service <<-->> Our ASP.net Web API <<-->> Our Front End

Developers had created .net classes in Web API by transforming Third Party API JSON response.

Now the issue arises when Third party adds/removes and updates their classes. our code break as some of properties are not present in our api.

**Is there any way we can automatically update the classes?**

**Should follow alternative approach rather than creating classes upfront?**

Comment: This is too broad, you need to provide specific information about the service, like how you know the classes have changed, what error messages you are receiving and if these new fields are fields that your code needs to know about. Also do you know what the classes have changed to, how do you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is that your API has some *proxy* class definitions that are used to communicate with a 3rd party API. This is a common approach, many APIs publish their meta-data specifically to support this type of implementation.

> If the 3rd party API was designed for public or at least your consumption, then you should contact their developers for support first, most API providers will happily share code examples or even pre-compiled client assemblies to make it easier to access their APIs.

If the 3rd party API has queryable meta-data, then you could use Visual Studio Connected Services, or T4 templates to generate out the classes.

If you are only using a small sub-set of their API, and the changes are in areas of the API that you do not use, then you might be able to manually interact with the API by constructing and parsing the request and response messages manually or use anonymous type serialization.

There are many techniques available, however the implementation would be highly specific to the type of service you are interacting with

Comment: Let me put more info on how developers created proxy classes in ASP.net API.
They did POST using SOAPUI .Copied the JSON response and pasted as class in Visual studio. it worked flawlessly once developers wrote client , update the values and posting it back to Third party API.
but. 
When in case in future Third party API makes any changes to their classes, we have to know it beforehand and need to update our source.

I am looking something like in WCF, update Service Reference would bring latest changes to your code.

Comment: Normally the 3rd party would publish updates to let you know that changes are coming and how to adapt. This sounds like you might be using a service that was not intended for your use, not a big deal but its something worth keeping in mind, especially if there are other more developer friendly service providers you could be using. T4, or Connected services would give you the same ability to "Update Service Reference", you can't just switch of WCF though unless the service is WCF compliant.